# Ways to structure an application that has two clear parts

Tags: mysql, database, api, database-design, architecture

I am in a project that has an infinite amount of tables, We have to come to a solution that brings scalability to the platform, and we don't seem to figure out what would be a really good one.

The platform is a job seeker, so it has two clear parts, candidates, and companies.

We've been thinking and have come to those posible solutions to re-estructure the current database, as it is a monster.

- 2 API's 2 Databases: This way would take a lot of database migration work, but would define very clearly the different parts of the platform.
- 2 API's 1 Database: Doing this, the database work would be reduced to normalize what we have now, but we would still have the two parts of the platform logically separated.
- 1 API 1 Database: Normalize the database, and do everything in the same API, trying to logically separate everything, making it scalable but at the same time accesible from one part to the other.

Right now I am more into the 1 API 1 Database solution, but we would like to read some experienced users to make the final choice.

Thank you!

Comment: Having multiple 'identical' tables is usually "bad schema design".  An "infinite" number of tables is really bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was in a situation kind of like yours some years ago. I will try to express my thoughts on how we handled it. All this might sound opinionated but each and every task is different, therefore the implementations are as well.

The two largest problems I notice:

- Having an infinite number of tables is the first sign that your current database schema design is a [Big Ball of Mud](http://www.laputan.org/mud/).
- Acknowledging that you have a [monster database](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-fb66g9t0eOU/TlneaYQDPWI/AAAAAAAAAkg/dnwdQw6O5Zs/s1600/monsterdatabase.jpg) indicates that you better start refactoring it to smaller pieces. Yes I know it's *never* easy.

It would add a lot more value to your question if you would show us some of the architectural details/parts of your codebase, so we could give better suited ideas.

Please forgive me for linking [Domain Driven Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) related information sources. I know that DDD is *not* about any technological fluff, however the *strategy* you need to choose is super important and I think it brings value to this post.

---

## Know your problem domain

Before you start taking your database apart you should clearly understand how your problem domain works. To put it simply: the problem domain definition in short is the domain of the business problems you are trying to *solve* with the strategy you are going to apply.

#### Pick your *strategy*

The most important thing here is: the business value your strategy brings. The proposed strategy in this case is to make clear distinctions between your database objects.

#### Be *tactical*!

We chose the strategy, now we need to to define tactics applied to this refactoring. Our definition of our tactics here should be clearly set like:

- Separate the related database objects that belong together, this defines explicit boundaries.
- Make sure the connections between the regrouped database objects remain intact and are working. I'm talking about cross table/object references here.

---

## Let's get technical - the database

#### How to break things

I personally would split up your current schema to three individual separate parts:

1. Candidates
2. Companies
3. Common tables

#### Reasoning

By strategically splitting up these database objects you consciously separate these concerns. This separation lets you have a new thing: tactical *boundary*.

Each of your newly separated schemas now have different contexts, and different boundaries. For example there is the Candidates schemas [bounded context](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html). It groups together business concepts/rules/etc. The same applies to the Companies schema.

The only difference is the Common tables schema. This could serve as a [shared kernel](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/03/30/ddd-recognising-relationships-between-bounded-contexts/) -a bridge, if you like- between your other databases, containing all the shared tables that every other schema needs to reach.

#### Outcome

All that has been said could bring you up to a level where you can:

- Backup/restore faster and more conveniently
- Scale database instances separately
- Easily set/monitor the access of database objects defined per schema

---

## The API

#### How to glue things

This is the point where it gets really greasy, however implementing an API is *really dependent* on your business use case. I personally would design two different public API's.

#### Example

1. For Candidates
2. For Companies

The same design principles apply here as well. The only difference here is that I think there is no added business value to add an API for the Common tables. It could be just a simple database schema which both of these main API's could query or send commands to.

Comment: @CarlosFdev happy to help! Please see the now edited version.

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion, seperating databases results in some content management difficulties. Both of these seperate parts will contain exactly same tables like job positions, cities, business areas etc. How will you maintain these tables? Will you insert country "Zimbabwe" to both of them? What if their primary keys not equal? At some point you will need to use data from these seperated databases and which record of "Zimbabwe" will be used? I'm not talking about performance but using same database for these two project will be make life easier for you. Also we are in cloud age and you can scale your single database service/server/droplet as you want. For clearity of modules, you can define your naming conventions. For example if table is used by both parts, add prefix "common_", if table only used by candidates use "candidate_" etc.

For API, you can use same methodology, too. Define 3 different API part. Common, candidates and companies. But in this way, you should code well-tested authentication and authorization layer for your API.

If I were you, I'd choose the 1 API, 1 Database.

***If it fails***, seperating 1 API to 2 API or 1 Database to 2 Database is much easier then merging them (humble opinion...)